# Datagrid Row Border Issue- Missing border in certain rows

Tags: datagrid

I have a dynamic datagrid my Silverlight application. I have set datagrid style, row style, and cell style. The datagrid when loaded hides border of certain rows. Everything looks good in the default style. I'm unable to find reason for this. Please help.

Pelease note: BasicColor are some defined colors.

```
   <!--DataGridStyle : Sets the DataGrid Style : Selected Cell Background, Mouse Hover Background, etc-->
    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="gridcontrol:DataGrid" >
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="{StaticResource BasicColor1}" />
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="{StaticResource BasicColor1}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BasicColor6}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="{StaticResource BasicColor9}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="{StaticResource BasicColor4}"/>
    </Style>


<!--DataGridCol : Sets the Style of the Content of the Cell in the Datagrid-->
        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellContentStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BasicColor6}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
            <Setter Property="FontStretch" Value="SemiCondensed"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        </Style>


   <Style TargetType="gridcontrol:DataGridRow" x:Key="DataGridRowStyle">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/> 
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>![enter image description here][1]
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
   </Style>
```